# How to generate a url with Cloudinary Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cloudinary

I am using **Cloudinart on Angular** and I want to generate a Cloudinary url.

```
<cl-image public-id="public_id">
                                <cl-transformation height="270" width="480" crop="fill"/>
                            </cl-image>
```

The image tag is generated with the above code. Is it possible to generate only a URL so that I can use it as a background image of the div?

Comment: Angular Cloudinary plugin provides another one directive [cl-href](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular#manipulation-url-generation-directives---cl-src-cl-href-cl-srcset). Perhaps that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var url = cloudinary.url("public_id", {height: 270, width: 480, crop: "fill"});
```

Comment: i am using angular only.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The mentioned code snippet is a pure javascript code. This uses Cloudinary's core javascript library which is automatically included when using Cloudinary's Angular library. See: https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/js/angular.cloudinary.js#L164-L164